# Standard duty cycle of fridge compressor?

Tags: compressor, fridge

I have a refrigerator which has compressor duty cycle of about 50% percent.

It’s set on 2 out of 5 which is the highest setting. It basically works for 12-13 minutes and then it’s of for about 16 minutes, and then cycle repeats.

Is this OK value?

Quoting [Targeting Refrigerators for Repair or Replacement](http://www.kouba-cavallo.com/art/REFRIG7a.pdf):

> One can begin by recognizing two very common characteristics of most refrigerators.
>   Over a broad range of models and vintages, the operating characteristics of properly operating
>   refrigerators under reasonable temperature conditions appear the same. A refrigerator turns on,
>   runs for a while, turns off and is off for a while. It then turns on again and the cycle repeats. A
>   typical,steady-state cycle is about 40 minutes with the duty cycle, or per cent running time, being
>   about 50 percent for standard temperature differences between the food compartment of the
>   refrigerator and the room in which the refrigerator is placed.
>    In other words, a typical, properly
>   operating refrigerator runs about 20 minutes and is off 20 minutes.

Comment: My side x side runs after being closed all night runs about 25 min, then off for 54 min, now that I replaced all the temp sensors with genuine GE from parts pros (many fakers out there give a clear plastic zip lock bag with a printed stick on lable; their sensors don't work right below 20F),the genuine GE parts come blue bags with special dbl green strip on the wires BEWARE those on amazon who say they are GE and even General Electric but are no, send you garbage which makes your fridge think its higher temp than it is (Ie registers 5F when its really 0 or -10 etc) so your fridge runs forever"

Comment: Duty cycle will depend on how efficient your fridge is as well as where you have set it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems normal from what I have read
Hope my math is correct:
I have a 20yr old 23.3cuft GE side-by-side refrig that runs 45% duty cycle (18min on, 22min off or 18/(18+22) = 18/40 = 45%, after refrig door has been closed for >8hrs.

With the current rating of 11.6 amps at 110v so this is ~.547kw/hr (110v*11.6*.45)
guessing off the top of my head newer compressors & fans don't use this much current so if a new ref will run at same 45% duty cycle the cost savings will be directly proportionate to the amperage reduction (i.e. 25% reduction in amps = 25% reduction in electric bill)